# Threading an Infinite Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, infinite-loop, python-multithreading

```
def check_incoming_messages_to_client(incoming_chat_messages,uri_str, kill_threads_subscript):
    global kill_threads
    messaging = Pyro4.Proxy(uri_str)

    while(TRUE):
        if(messaging.get_connection() == 'yes'):
            msg = messaging.read_messages_to_client()
            if (msg):
                incoming_chat_messages.insert(END, msg)
        if(kill_threads[kill_threads_subscript]):
           print('break loop')
           break

print('start')
t1 = Thread(target=check_incoming_messages_to_client(incoming_chat_messages[length-1],uri_str, kill_threads_subscript))
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
print('end')
```

The code above only print `start` and not `end`. That means it was stuck in the infinite loop, which must not be because it was threaded. How will I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread(target=check_incoming_messages_to_client(incoming_chat_messages[length-1],uri_str, kill_threads_subscript))` *calls* your function, then passes the result as the `target` (except since it never ends, no result ever materializes, and you never even construct the `Thread`).

You want to pass the function *uncalled*, and the `args` separately so the *thread* calls it when it runs, rather than the main thread running it before the worker thread even launches:

```
t1 = Thread(target=check_incoming_messages_to_client,
            args=(incoming_chat_messages[length-1], uri_str, kill_threads_subscript))
```